# Domain name DNS problem

Tags: domain-name-system

I have domain name (novinhost.net) which is set as the primary dns pointers for my vps.
the problem here is it's not accessible from everywhere.
I checked the dns reports using the following url and there seems to be some problems and I can't figure out how to solve them.
[DNS Report](http://www.intodns.com/novinhost.net)
I wonder how can they be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The serial on the zone is 2011042301 so presumably 2011-04-23 is the date of the last change (it is 04-27 in the WHOIS)
There is no MX - and I know of at least a registry that won't accept NS change without a valid MX record (inhospitable, but reasonable).

Also, the DNS chnge will not take effect unless the proper registrar(s) render it effective by registring the NS change i n the upstream WHOIS database... what procedure did you follow to make that happen? As of now, novinhost.com appears to be parked at orderbox-dns.com.

Cheers,
alf

Comment: well I use the reseller-club panel to manage the DNS settings.  
fist of all i created 2 child name servers of my domain and set it's own DNSs on those child nameservers and then I set all other records like A,SOA,MX,NS...

Answer (score 3):

When did set your domain name as primary dns for your vps.

Usually the dns changes will take 24 to 48 hours to get resolved and after that you can view your domain with the new dns entries..